# Unity command-line build requires UnityEditor.BuildPipeline, but builds fail for missing 'UnityEditor' reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, command-line-interface

I am presently trying to create a batch file for a command-line build of a simple Unity project.
Current environment is:
* Windows 10
* Unity 2017.4.19f1 (Personal)
* Offline network

The project consists of just a simple scene that works fine in the UnityEditor. After failing to get a good build, I've stripped down my build script and batch file to the following:

**BareBoneBuild.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEditor;

namespace Assets.BuildScripts
{
    class BareBoneBuild
    {
        private static string windowsBuildFolderPath = "G:/dev/projects/SimpleProject";

        static void PerformBuild()
        {
            string[] scenes = { "Assets/Scenes/DetectionTest.cs" };
            BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, windowsBuildFolderPath + "/junk.exe", BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows, BuildOptions.None);
        }
    }
}
```

**BareBoneBuild.bat**

```
title Unity Build

echo Launching Unity Build...
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" ^
-batchmode ^
-projectPath G:\dev\projects\SimpleProject ^
-executeMethod Assets.BuildScripts.BareBoneBuild.PerformBuild ^
-quit ^
-logFile G:\dev\projects\SimpleProject\logs\BareBoneBuild.log

echo Build Finished!

PAUSE
```

**BareBoneBuild.log** (snippet)

```
...
-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: 1--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
Assets/BuildScripts/BareBoneBuild.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
- Finished compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll
Assets/BuildScripts/BareBoneBuild.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?**

(Filename: Assets/BuildScripts/BareBoneBuild.cs Line: 6)

DisplayProgressNotification: Build Failed
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

(Filename:  Line: -1)
...
```

*EVERY* tutorial, blog, youtube video, forum
* https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html
* http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/automating-unity3d-builds-with-fake
* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J3SmhGxO1Y
* others...that I don't have the links to

I've viewed states that BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer is the way to build a project from the command-line. BuildPipeline is inside the UnityEditor library.

What am I doing wrong? I'm still new to Unity, so any obvious solution is probably correct.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `using UnityEditor;` in a build. It is stripped of.

---

You only need this available in an editor script and not in a build so:

- Either use [`#if` pre-processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) wrapping everything using it like

  ```
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       using UnityEditor;
   #endif

   ...

   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       // anything using UnityEidtor e.g. the method or entire class
   #endif
  ```
- or in your case simply move the entire script into a folder called `Editor` which strippes of the entire script for a build (see [Special folder names](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)).

  This is actually also mentioned - though not well explained - by [your link](http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/automating-unity3d-builds-with-fake):

  > Then you would need a class in your Unity project **in an Editor folder** such as this Android example:
- or in newer Unity versions you can put it in a separate folder (with any name) and create an [`AssemblyDefinition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) and configure it so it is only compiled for the UnityEditor (see in particular [Creating an assembly for Editor code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#create-editor-assembly))

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I have compiled EXEs now!
I am amazed that such a little detail is overlooked in so many places! Especially since it's absent in the official Unity documentation!

Comment: First - the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html)  have an example class for custom build that is using UnityEditor. 
Second - BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer() is declared in UnityEditor namespace, so without it you can't really have your project built.

Comment: @rostok maybe I'm missing your point but First - yes, that is most probably what OP's code is based on since it is exactly that + a batch file using the command line arguments .. and Second - yes, but it is still only valid within the UnityEditor itself and won't exist in a build of the application => as I stated in my answer there are two ways to make sure that script is not included in the build itself

Comment: @derHugo I have wrongly assumed you suggest removing the UnityEditor from the build class that is accessed from batch. Sorry for the confusion, your answer is good.